# Cannot access google translate element through chrome console

Tags: web-scraping, google-translate, google-developers-console

I am trying to extract multiple-translations for a keyword on Google translate, but I can't access this data using selectors. There is any possible way to achieve the result?

That's an image for the elements I am trying to select:
https://ibb.co/5TN3Rzh

I found the same elements on this request:

```
https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=webapp&sl=en&tl=zh-CN&hl=en&dt=at&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&source=bh&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=1&tk=929845.561291&q=reuse
```

But I don't know how to calculate this `tk` variable.

I already try the google translate API but they don't provide multiple-translations.

Please, could you explain why can't I access these elements? And how could I do it?